# My gem cannot see a dictionary text file, I cannot get the path

Tags: ruby, file, dictionary

I wrote an implementation of the hangman game. (It is played on the terminal). The game is working fine but I usually have some problems getting my program to open a dictionary txt file from where the word will be generated. Below is my code for generating the word

```
def word_generator(min, max)
    words = File.open("../dictionary.txt"), "r").readlines.map!(&:chomp)
    level_words = words.select { |i| i.length >= min && i.length <= max }
    random_index = rand(level_words.length)
    @game_word = level_words[random_index]
end
```

This approach works fine when I play my game locally and the dictionary text file is just one directory level away from my ruby file. Here is the problem:
When I package the project as a gem, and install it. It will throw this error `in initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen  /Users/andeladev/Desktop/paitin_hangman/bin/dictionary.txt (Errno::ENOENT)`. It will only run fine when I put the text file in the present working directory of the terminal.

How do I go about writing the path in the argument passed to `File.open` that will tell the program to look for the file in the gem path rather than the present working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
file_name = File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), '../dictionary.txt')
words = File.open(file_name, "r").readlines.map!(&:chomp)
```

Comment: I tried the code, it still did not see the dictionary file, but it gave me a clue as to where to get it, so I added one more `../` and that was it. The code I used was `file_name = File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), '../../dictionary.txt')`. Thanks a lot